# How to install Kivy with dependencies in Windows 10 using pip?

Tags: python, android, windows, kivy

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [10 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-67.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
[end of output]

I was trying to install kivy with "pip install kivy[full]" but isted of installing kivy suprocess error occored then I tryed installing subprocess with "pip install subprocess.run" it was installed sucessfully but again the same error is occruing

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, try to install Kivy using the pre-built wheel from the Kivy website. Download the wheel and install it using the pip command:

`pip install <path-to-wheel-file>`

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install "kivy[full]"
```

should work, are you getting problems with this exact syntax too?

if you are installing from requirements.txt file be sure to remove the "", your file should contain:

```
kivy[full]
```

and the command to install it is:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```